# Bootstrap date time picker only picks up current date when maxdate is set

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, symfony, datetimepicker

I'm having an issue with the Bootstrap datetimepicker in that when I set the `maxDate` to `new Date` (as in, today) it only ever shows that date as the default selected, rather than the one that it's trying to pull from the database.

I'm working in Symfony3. I have a date time picker instance in my form for the date of birth of a dog, as follows:

```
$builder->add('dob', DateType::class, array(
    'required' => true,
    'widget' => 'single_text',
    'label' => 'Date of Birth',
    'html5' => false,
    'attr' => ['class' => 'datepicker form-control']
));
```

And my instantiation:

```
$('.datepicker').datetimepicker( {
    format: 'DD-MM-YYYY',
    maxDate: new Date,
    defaultDate: false
});
```

Now, if I remove `maxDate`, it's fine and pulls out the correct date as saved in the database and on a blank form it comes out blank waiting for input. However, since this is a date of birth field I don't want the availability for future dates to be entered.

Is there something I am doing wrong here for this to happen? Or maybe do I need an additional setting? Help is appreciated.

EDIT:

This is my controller code on how I'm passing through the information for the form fields, where `$request->get('id')` is passed as a `$_GET` parameter:

```
$dog = $repo->findOneBy(array('id' => $request->get('id')));
$form = $this->createForm(DogEditType::class, $dog);
```

Comment: how are you assigning the date that is coming from the database? I cannot see where you have assigned that?

Comment: I've added the code at the bottom of the question. DogEditType is the form type which includes the dob field

Comment: I think you should set the date as following

`$('.datepicker').datetimepicker( {
    format: 'DD-MM-YYYY',
    maxDate: new Date,
    setDate: '<?= your database date here ?>'
});`
, and also remove the `defaultDate: false`

Comment: another solution will be `$(".datepicker").datetimepicker("update", your database date here);`

Comment: I think you may misunderstand how Symfony works. You don't pass the value in the javascript, the javascript merely instantiates the field everywhere on the site. I'll try using jQuery instead of Bootstrap date picker and see if that works